# mobile app database ORM and sync with server

Tags: android, database, backend

I'm writing a mobile app for travel destination information. It will be nice if you guys can help me find a(or a stack of) good library or framework to do the following elegantly.

The server database has data for multiple travel destinations(say 100). The data for each destination can be from 10MB to 100MB in size. The data contains binary and text. Data can be categorized into classes and classes have relationships. For example, "TravelDestitation" is a class, it has "introduction" text property and "headerImage" file property, "Resturant" is a class too, and it has multiple-to-one relationship with "TravelDestination".

So the thing I want is a unified interface, so I can:

1. access database just like accessing java objects(ORM and DAO)
2. query data from local data storage if data exist in local storage
3. if not exist in local, fetch the data from server transparently and cache in local storage

Also, I want the client to be able to:

1. pre-fetch some portion of the data, like download all data related to one travel destination so user can use offline.
2. keep the pre-fetched data up-to-date when I make changes to data on server.
3. prefer self-hosted opensource solution.

Thanks!

Comment: For Making api calls use the Retrofit library and for the database use Realm,Powerful combination to cater ur requirement